# How to copy newly added records from one database to another database in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am having two database with two different names but the tables and procedures are same. I need to copy only the **missing records from the original database to the second database** with same structure. Can anyone help me to find solution for this.

Comment: Replication, linked servers, left joins, redgate tool...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO a
SELECT  b.*
FROM    DB1.dbo..table_a a, DB2.dbo..table_a b
        WHERE a.ID != b.ID
```

Comment: Thank you but we also need the modified records also..

Comment: then TRUNCATE and INSERT and please edit your Q regarding updated record also

Comment: @Varghese:- Then why not simply truncate the records from the second database and then simply do a simple insert as that would make your job much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just drop the second database, detach the original, copy and rename the database files, then reattach the original and the copy? Is there anything in the second database you need to keep? There's plenty of ways to dupe a database.

Comment: Yes... the second database is like backup database.. Copying only newly records is for avoiding network traffic... Thank you

Comment: In that case you want to look into things like replication, linked servers, hot backups, log shipping and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If its a one time activity then you can use the  "Import Data" task by right-click on your DB name and then tasks.  You can run it from the original database you want to copy the data.

Also if its a regular activity then you can create a replication process for it.